# Unity post method send string but doesn't class object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, webapi

As you can see in the title this method send string but doesn't send my class object. This method is working correctly in Windows Form app.
The method:

```
async public Task<bool> PostHttp()
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        RegModel model = new RegModel()
        {
            UserMail = "ca35",
            UserPass = "1111"
        };

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5070/");
        string postData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
        Debug.Log(postData);

        var content = new StringContent(postData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var result = await client.PostAsync("api/doPost",content);

        string resultContent = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Debug.Log(resultContent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

My class:

```
public class RegModel
{
    public string UserMail;
    public string UserPass;
}
```

and API:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/RemoteOperations")]
public class RegController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/api/doGet")]
    public RegModel Get()
    {
        var _regModel = new RegModel()
        {
               UserMail = "deneme",
               UserPass ="denemepass"
        };

        return _regModel;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("/api/doPost")]
    public string Post(RegModel regModel)
    {
        string result = regModel.UserMail;

        return "ok "+ result;
    }
}
```

The debugged model JSON is:

> {"UserMail":"ca35","UserPass":"1111"}

But RegModel.UserMail and RegModel.UserPass are both null. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a new Web App server, and/or your server is using System.Text.Json as it's JSON serialiser, then you can resolve the issue in one of two ways:

The first is to use properties instead of fields. This can be an issue if your client side serialiser wants you to use fields instead of properties, in which case you'd need to define your model twice, once with fields on the client and the server side with properties:

```
public class RegModel
{
    public string UserMail { get; set; }
    public string UserPass { get; set; }
}
```

The second method is to allow System.Text.Json to read fields on the server by adding the `JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields` option:

```
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers ( )
    .AddJsonOptions ( options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.IncludeFields = true );
```

Comment: thank you soo much I've been searching for 3 days bro thank you so much thank youu @Milan Egon Votrubec

Answer (score 0):

Networks cannot send objects. You can convert the object to JSON or XML format and send it over the network. Prepare a model to receive data to the server and receive data using this model. I think you understand that